# Как заменить ON CONFLICT в RedShift?

Tags: postgresql, redshift

Как правильно заменить в RedShift параметр ON CONFLICT при попытке обновить данные в строке, если нашли дубликат? Потому что как я понял, RedShift не воскпринимает ON CONFLICT. Во всяком случае у меня выдает ошибку на этот параметр.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас заменил так (взял из официальной документации):

```
begin transaction;

update target 
set col1 = stage.col1, 
col2 = stage.col2, 
col3 = 'expression' 
from stage 
where target.primarykey = stage.primarykey 
and target.distkey = stage.distkey 
and target.col3 > 'last_update_time' 
and (target.col1 != stage.col1 
or target.col2 != stage.col2 
or target.col3 = 'filter_expression');

insert into target
(select col1, col2, 'expression'
from stage);

end transaction;
```